# Sort json list from another list

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I'm trying to sort a json list from another list.
example:

```
jsonList = [{'id': 'das', 'name': 'something'}, {'id': 'rtn', 'name': 'Something Else'}, {'id': 'ddsn', 'name': 'Something ElseElse'}]
orderList = ['rtn', 'ddsn', 'das']

goodList = someFunction(jsonList, orderList )
```

I need the output to be the json list sorted by the id:

```
goodList = [{'id': 'rtn', 'name': 'Something Else'}, {'id': 'ddsn', 'name': 'Something ElseElse'}, {'id': 'das', 'name': 'something'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`goodList = sorted(jsonList, key=lambda x: orderList.index(x['id']))`

or if you want just sort by id

`sorted(jsonList, key=lambda x : x['id'])`