# Sort JSON list from another list in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort a JSON list from another list, by a Value in the JSON list.

```
var jsonList = [{'id': 'das', 'name': 'something'}, {'id': 'rtn', 'name': 'Something Else'}, {'id': 'ddsn', 'name': 'Something ElseElse'}];

var orderList = ['rtn', 'ddsn', 'das'];

var goodList = someFunction(jsonList, orderList);
```

I need the output to be it sorted from the orderList by the id in the json list.

```
goodList = [{'id': 'rtn', 'name': 'Something Else'}, {'id': 'ddsn', 'name': 'Something ElseElse'}, {'id': 'das', 'name': 'something'}]
```

I asked the [same question for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64814131/sort-json-list-from-another-list), but now I need it in JavaScript.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

JS can also sort with a custom comparator:

```js
const jsonList = [{'id': 'das', 'name': 'something'}, {'id': 'rtn', 'name': 'Something Else'}, {'id': 'ddsn', 'name': 'Something ElseElse'}];

const orderList = ['rtn', 'ddsn', 'das'];
jsonList.sort((a, b) => orderList.indexOf(a.id) - orderList.indexOf(b.id));
console.log(jsonList);
```